# Parse variable from javascript like BeautifulSoup parses HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I do not need a screen scraper.

I just want to extract a variable from the static js. e.g piece of javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            has_map = true;

        new hip.Events({
            has_date_picker: false,
            has_big_button: true,
            has_map: has_map,
            map_selector: 'event-map',
            coordinates: 'POINT (-79.4004249999999985 43.6524020000000021)',
            marker_icon: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/imageupload/static/new_media/images/map-marker.png'
        });

    });
```

Let's say I want the value for the key `marker_icon` (the url in this example). Is there any library in python or should I do it the ugly way: regex?

Comment: You'll have to do it the Ugly Way, with a regex or string manipulation.